# Updating Label Multiple Time in One Function

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a kivy windows, and I have to change a label which shows reading dataset progress.

When reading dataset is being executed, I want show the progress as a text in kivy window, but it seems kivy just finished a logic first and then update the label. Here is my code:

Function to run kivy:

```
class loadingView(App):
    def build(self):
        container = Container()
        Clock.schedule_once(container.run, 1)

        return container
```

and this is a class contains a function to run a logic:

```
class Container(GridLayout, object):
     procTxt = ObjectProperty()
     procProgbar = ObjectProperty()

     def run(self, *args):
        self.procTxt.text = "Reading first dataset"
        self.procProgbar.value += 10
        # I read first dataset here

        self.procTxt.text = "Reading second dataset"
        self.procProgbar.value += 10
        # I read second dataset here

        self.procTxt.text = "Reading third dataset"
        self.procProgbar.value += 10
        # I read third dataset here

        # Read dataset done
        self.procTxt.text = "DONE"
```

But when I run the code, the kivy window showed up, delayed for some time, and immediately update the Label into "DONE".

There is a pause in every reading progress. But it seems the label isn't updating. Is there anyway to update a label everytime the app read the dataset?

Comment: if this is the run method, the changes are not noticed, firstly because the changes have less priority than the synchronous tasks and second because the task you perform is very fast.

Comment: @eyllanesc but i have tried to compare and print something into console when reading a progreess. it consumed a little bit of time when reading one progress. And a console shows that (i print "Reading first...", "Reading second..."). But the label doesn't update. maybe yaaa, just like you said. It has less priority

Comment: Review the following: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html, 
As noted tasks such as repainting (when you put a new text is repainted) is performed when synchronous tasks do not occupy the loop.

Comment: @eyllanesc is it possible to use eventdispatcher? i have read that, but not quite understand.

Comment: eventdispatcher is the same as the xxxproperty, it will not do it, as I tell you even if you manage to show it to be so fast the execution will not be observed.

Comment: If you separate your `run()` method into three different methods (one for each dataset), then call the first as you do now, and call subsequent with something like `Clock.schedule_once(self.run2, 0)` at the end of the previous dataset read. I think it would work.